# Powermock + TestNG not loading configuration.properties

Tags: java, testng, powermock

I'm trying to ignore the slf4j errors globally and found the following documentation

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/PowerMock-Configuration

I added the configuration.properties inside the resources folder, like this:

`/src/test/resources/org/powermock/extensions`

And it only contains:

`powermock.global-ignore="org.apache.log4j.*"`

Regarding the documentation, I do not need to add any configuration bean for powermock, but powermock is ignoring completely the load of this properties.

My Powermock dependencies looks like:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-classloading-xstream</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

NOTE: If I add `@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.log4j.*")` works just fine, but I still have one

`log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.Appender" variable.`

That is showing up when the testNG context is loading to start the tests execution, and even if I turn all the stack trace for mvn test, I can't figure out which class is throwing the error.

Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

When used in properties file there should be no double quotes.

```
@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.log4j.*")
```

in the class should be replaced by

```
powermock.global-ignore=org.apache.log4j.*
```

in the configuration.properties file.

Comment: Note, spaces and double quotes are not allowed in the configuration.properties file. See: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/989